# What does the prefix 'ab-' mean in the Latin verb 'abundare' ?

Tags: etymology, latin

> [abound (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=abound&searchmode=none)
>       early 14c., from Old French abonder "to abound, be abundant, come together in great numbers" (12c.), from Latin abundare "overflow, run over," 
>   from Latin ***ab-* "off"** (see [ab-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ab-&allowed_in_frame=0)) + *undare* "rise in a wave," from unda "water, wave" (see [water](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=water&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.1)).

What is the meaning of "off", while during a "rise in a wave" ? Is there some [hypotaxis](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hypotaxis)?

Comment: Ever tried to walk fast carrying a full cup of coffee? The coffee rises in waves set off by the motion and sloshes over from the top of the cup, if you're not careful. BTW, _hypotaxis_ is a literary term, not a linguistic one. You've got to stop trying to learn grammar from a dictionary. Greek terms were coined for Greek by ancient Greek grammarians, who had extremely odd notions about language (where 'language' = 'Homeric Greek'; other people spoke barbaric languages, not real ones), and are rarely useful. But they do impress people, for sure.

Comment: @jlawler Thanks. So the PREfix truly represents an event that occurs AFTER the root; this (unexpected) syntagma confused me. A friend broached the term 'hypotaxis' to me; so I'll tell him. I never desire to impress people, but to impress truth upon myself.

Comment: Prefix goes at the beginning of the word. That's all it means. Has nothing to do with event timing.

Comment: Have we mentioned metaphor? You seem to be treating metaphoric uses as if they were literal; there's a ***BIG*** difference. And most meanings are ultimately metaphoric, if you go back far enough.

Comment: If you're asking about a Latin word, then please base the question on a Latin definition.